# Why SoundJuicer and Rythmbox don't allow me to tweak the cd ripping profiles?

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, sound-juicer

I installed an Ubuntu 12.04 server then added only the packages I needed to have a Gnome 3 desktop but something must still be missing. In fact neither Rhythmbox or SoundJuicer allow me to tweak the cd ripping profiles.

Any idea what it's missing?

Answer (score 0):

I used another ripping software, goobox (this is just a "CD player", but have capability to rip CD). This program showed profile selection button with no problem and worked very fine. You can find software "goobox" at Ubuntu software center.